# Why my code reads a line of 8 integers but gives my InputMissMatch error when reading 16?

Tags: arrays, string, netbeans

I want to read multiple lines from a text file which consists of numbers 0s and 1s and store the lines in a 2D Array. 
My code works fine when it reads 2*2, 4*4, and 8*8 array. However, it gives me this error message (java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "0010101111011011") when it reads 16*16 and more. This is my code.

```
public static void storingIntegers(Scanner input, int [][]array){


          for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
              //This variable reads the line which contains the numbers
          int row= input.nextInt();
                 for (int j =  array[i].length-1;  j>=0; j--) {
            //this line will take the last number in the line and store it in the array from index 0
            //start storing from the last index  
            array[i][j] = row%10;
            row=row/10;

           }
       }

   }
```

I wanna know why this message is given and how to fix this problem ?

here is a sample input of 16*16 array of numbers that must be read from the file

```
0010101111011011
1101101111011011
0010110011110011
1110110011110011
1101101011011010
0010101011110011
1111001111011010
0011111111110011
0010101111011011
1101101111011011
0010110011110011
1110110011110011
1101101011011010
0010101011110011
1111001111011010
0011111111110011
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()), `nextInt()` will throw an `InputMismatchException` ...

> if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

The range of Java integers is from (-2^31) to (2^31 - 1) = 2147483647, and since you are not formatting the value as a binary integer, your values are probably getting out of range. Notice the MAX_VALUE of an integer in Java has 10 digits in base 10, and you are getting the Exception while trying to format 16-digit integers.

Maybe you could try specifying a [radix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)):

```
int row = input.nextInt(2); //this way you read integers in base 2
```

Or if you want to store the number in the same format it comes, you could try retrieving a BigInteger:

```
BigInteger row = input.nextBigInteger();
```

Comment: I tried your ways. Yes they fix the error message but they don't solve the problem. Actually I solved it with another way. I stored the numbers as (long) in x variable then took the %10 of it and then stored this number in another (int) variable (y) and then store (y) in the int array.

Comment: I see. Well, still a valid answer –especially the BigInteger part–, since you'll run into the same problems once you supply larger numbers. Also, may it be that you are losing precision with your implementation? I'll bet you are throwing away some significant bits of the collected number.